# Android Time Zone UTC to current conversion not working

Tags: android, timezone

Im trying to convert  a given date formated in UTC timezone and then converting to the current timezone. But its not working properly, here's the code:

```
public String CurrentTimeZone(Date value){

    SimpleDateFormat sdf= getReaderFormatter();
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    sdf.format(value);
    return getCurrentTimeZone().format(value);
}
```

The problem is that the date value still remains in the current time zone after formating it with the UTC one, so the conversion ends up being from "current timezone -> current timezone" and not UTC timezone -> current timezone....

Comment: public SimpleDateFormat getCurrentTimeZone(){
  
   SimpleDateFormat fmt = getReaderFormatter();
   // set the timezone  
   fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

  return fmt;
  
 }